# from qiskit.aqua import... ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: programming, qiskit

Dear team and developers.

I am using qiskit on Python 36, windows 64bits

I have the same identical problem of [Import from qiskit-aqua error](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5729/import-from-qiskit-aqua-error)

But the suggested solution (installing Numpy+mkl, I did it!) is not the solution in my case as the error persists and I am desperate.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\root\eclipse-workspace\Dir\file.py", line 11, in <module>
    from qiskit.aqua.components.uncertainty_models import UniformDistribution, UnivariateVariationalDistribution 
  File "C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\qiskit\aqua\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .utils.backend_utils import (get_aer_backend,
  File "C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\qiskit\aqua\utils\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .qp_solver import optimize_svm
  File "C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\qiskit\aqua\utils\qp_solver.py", line 18, in <module>
    from cvxopt import matrix, solvers
  File "C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cvxopt\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    import cvxopt.base
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I re-installed everything, all is up to date.

Please help.

Comment: This issue on the `cvxopt` github might help: https://github.com/cvxopt/cvxopt/issues/127. I have also seen a couple answers that people have said have solved the issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14778178/import-cvxopt-base-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found

Comment: @MatthewStypulkoski Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/cvxopt/cvxopt/issues/127#issuecomment-411973792 works

Comment: Try using this `from qiskit import *`
After the import, it would work.
On which IDE are you running your code?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about quantum computing (similarly to how a question about a failure to load DLL for *de novo* assembly would not be a question about biology).